# Adapt/Rewrite all Links in an HTML Document that is not necessarily XML Compliant

Tags: java, html, scala, url-rewriting

I'm in the process of writing a reverse proxy. Parts of that is obviously rewriting the links to reflect the mapping. What is the best approach to achieve that?
As I'm doing that with Scala I was looking for a tidy approach with JSoup or something similar but they all seem quite slow for something this central.

So I was wondering, is there a better approach to take?

Thank you for opinions!

Regards
Alessandro

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is why not to use regex to process HTML...

Comment: Well my intent was not to use regex to actually parse, but to use regex to actually find URLs, which *could* be more reasonable. But in the end, i'm just interested in other opinion and/or solutions.